# How do I round to the nearest 0.5 with following sequense

Tags: .net

I have to display ratings and for that i need increments as follows:

If the number is 1.0 it should be equal to 1

If the number is 1.1 should be equal to 1

If the number is 1.2 should be equal to 1.5

If the number is 1.3 should be equal to 1.5

If the number is 1.4 should be equal to 1.5

If the number is 1.5 should be equal to 1.5

If the number is 1.6 should be equal to 1.5

If the number is 1.7 should be equal to 1.5

If the number is 1.8 should be equal to 2.0

If the number is 1.9 should be equal to 2.0

If the number is 2.0 should be equal to 2.0

If the number is 2.1 should be equal to 2.0

and so on...

Is there a simple way to compute the required values?

Comment: IS this a story ? please format your question.

Comment: Are you sure you want 1.2 to round up to 1.5?

Comment: yes.i need to round 1.2 as 1.5

Comment: You didn't describe what should happen for values between `1.1` and `1.2`.

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.2 is nearer 1.0 than 1.5,  your're not really rounding to nearest 0.5 and the standard Math.Round() function isn't really going to do the whole job for you.

You're going to need to shift the value slightly when there is a .2  in the sequence.

Try using this:

```
var shiftBy = ((int)Math.Round(v*10) % 10 == 2) ? 0.1 : 0;

var nearest = Math.Round((v + shiftBy)*2)/2.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be this to round `v`:

```
v = Math.Round(v*2.0) / 2.0;
```

but this will round `1.2` *down* to `1.0`. (It's a bit strange that both 1.2 and 1.7 should round to 1.5)

Comment: v = Math.Round(v*2.0) / 2.0;<p>this format 1.2 down to 1.0</p>but for me 1.2 should round as 1.5

Comment: if 1.2 must be 1.5 then 1.7 should be 2, no ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
r = Math.Floor(v) + 0.5*( 
                        Math.Floor(v + 0.8) - Math.Floor(v) 
                      + Math.Floor(v + 0.2) - Math.Floor(v) )
```

This can be simplified as:

```
r = 0.5 * ( Math.Floor(v + 0.8) + Math.Floor(v + 0.2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double nr = 15.9;
double rounded = (int)nr;
double rest = Math.Round(nr - rounded, 5);
if(0.2 <= rest && rest <= 0.7)
  rounded += 0.5;
else if (0.7 < rest)
  rounded += 1;
```

Tested with 15.0 > 15.9. Seems to work OK.